# What would be hold some number of Double[] in java?

Tags: java, arrays, list

A List or collection or something other?

I would be storing between 10 and 20 Double[].

I would want to add more maybe, retrieve them.

Comment: This is very difficult to follow.  Please edit to make it clearer what you really need - or remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean where you could store your doubles for in-memory usage?
Go for an ArrayList.

```
List<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();
// store
list.add(10.0);
list.add(15.0);
// Retrieve
for (Double d : list) {
  System.out.println(d);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A `Double[][]` will do the trick.